# MYSQL: select all rows from table matching a combination and the opposite

Tags: mysql

my table looks like this

```
ID - col1 - col2
=====================
1  - 115  -  3
2  - 3    -  115
3  - 110  -  121
4  - 12   -  115
5  - 115  -  121
6  - 115  -  65
```

I want to select all row WHERE `col1 = 115`
which will output a simple table with all row matching 115
so I did

```
SELECT * from myTable WHERE col1= 115
```

and that's the easy part. Now, at the same time, I need to mark somehow all the rows that are matching the opposite values
in this case `

> 3 and 115, given also 115 and 3 exists

not that I won't "mark" 12 | 115 because 115|12 does not exist

the desired output should be

```
ID - col1 - col2 - mark
========================
1  - 115  -  3   - true
5  - 115  -  121 - false
6  - 115  -  65  - false
```

I hope I made myself clear...
`

Comment: Should id 2 be true or false?

Comment: @Bleach it doesn't matter, i dont need to know as I only need to know every row selected as an opposite "twin"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the table to itself, known as a "self-join". The query returns all the data from the first instance of the table, but only joins the records from the second instance that are the opposite of the first instance. So, where there is a reverse match, there will be data in all joined columns, and where there isn't a reverse match, ID, col1, and col2 will return null data on the joined columns. Then, use an "if" statement to look for null values on the joined data). See code below:

```
SELECT
    nt1.ID,
    nt1.col1,
    nt1.col2,
    if(ID.col1 IS NULL, 'False', 'True') AS `Mark`
FROM
    new_test AS nt1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    new_test AS nt2
    ON
    (
    nt1.col1 = nt2.col2
    AND
    nt1.col2 = nt2.col1
    )
WHERE 
    nt1.col1 = 115;
```

Note that we're matching col1's with col2's in the join, which gets you your reversed numbers.

Code I used to setup test:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_test;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_test (
    id int not null,
    col1 int,
    col2 int
);


INSERT INTO new_test (ID, col1, col2) 
    VALUES
        (1,115,3),
        (2,3,115),
        (3,110,121),
        (4,12,115),
        (5,115,121),
        (6,115,65);
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I hadn't copied that part to my test environment. ... I always catch my mistakes eventually. :-) ... Good question that brings up a couple of really useful techniques (self-join; using multiple non-matched columns in a join, and the use of if statements). ... And worded a lot better than most.